# Copy a file with buffers of different sizes for read and write

Tags: c, file, buffer

I have been doing some practice problems for job interviews and I came across a function that I can't wrap my mind on how to tackle it. The idea is to create a function that takes the name of two files, and the allowed buffer size to read from file1 and allowed buffer size for write to file2. if the buffer size is the same, I know how to go trough the question, but I am having problems figuring how to move data between the buffers when the sizes are of different. Part of the constraints is that we have to always fill the write buffer before writing it to file. if file1 is not a multiple of file2, we pad the last buffer transfer with zeros.

```
// input: name of two files made for copy, and their limited buffer sizes
// output: number of bytes copied
int fileCopy(char* file1,char* file2, int bufferSize1, int bufferSize2){
int bytesTransfered=0;
int bytesMoved=o;
char* buffer1, *buffer2;
FILE *fp1, *fp2;

fp1 = fopen(file1, "r");
if (fp1 == NULL) { 
    printf ("Not able to open this file"); 
    return -1;
}

fp2 = fopen(file2, "w");
if (fp2 == NULL) {
    printf ("Not able to open this file"); 
    fclose(fp1); 
    return -1;
}

buffer1 = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*bufferSize1);
if (buffer1 == NULL) {
    printf ("Memory error");
    return -1;
}

buffer2 = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*bufferSize2);
if (buffer2 == NULL) {
    printf ("Memory error"); 
    return -1;
}

bytesMoved=fread(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1),1,fp1);

//TODO: Fill buffer2 with maximum amount, either when buffer1 <= buffer2 or buffer1 > buffer2
//How do I iterate trough file1 and ensuring to always fill buffer 2 before writing?

bytesTransfered+=fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2),1,fp2);

fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);

return bytesTransfered;
}
```

How should I write the while loop for the buffer transfers before the fwrites?

Comment: Definitely an artificial question, since if you're using `FILE *`'s to do the reading and writing, the stdio package is doing its own buffering on both the read and write sides, so the buffer sizes as seen in the high-level code have no relation to the actual read and write counts.  A "better" answer (though likely not what your instructor is looking for) would be to call `setvbuf` twice, to set up the correctly sized buffers on `fp1` and `fp2`, then write an ordinary single-buffer copying loop, and not worry about repacking at all, because stdio ends up doing it for you.

Comment: Please do not cast the return value of `malloc`

Comment: You should report errors on standard error.  When you fail to open a file, you should specify the file name in the error message.  You should end the error message with a newline.  You should attempt to allocate the memory before opening either file; it's more expensive if the files are opened and then the memory allocation fails.

Comment: There are two main cases to consider: (1) the read buffer is bigger than the write buffer, and (2) the read buffer is smaller than the write buffer. The other case — same size buffers — doesn't present any problems, of course. It isn't clear whether the sizes will be integral multiples of each other (could you have a 6KiB read buffer and a 7KiB write buffer?). You have to process case (1) differently from case (2). In case (1), you read a buffer full, then write parts of the big buffer into the write buffer and write it. If the read buffer is smaller, then you do several reads per write.

Comment: There are also the edge conditions to worry about — there's part of a write buffer full left in the read buffer, or vice versa.  These can all be handled if you think about it.  However, as already pointed out, this is a rather artificial question — there is lots of unnecessary buffer copying in progress unless you're careful.

Comment: @SteveSummit The parameters passed via `setvbuf()` are merely "suggestions".  Per **7.21.5.6  The `setvbuf` function** of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (emphasis mine): "If `buf` is not a null pointer, the array it points to **may be used** instead of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function and the argument `size` specifies the size of the array; otherwise, `size` **may** determine  the size of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function." If the IO to the file must be done using a buffer of a specific size, in general `setvbuf` fails.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point, thanks for the reminder.  But `setvbuf` et al. are clearly the closest we can come to *actually* controlling the read and write buffer sizes.  Mucking around with separate "read" and "write" buffers in user code, as the OP is trying to do, is some kind of an academic exercise at best, devoid of any practical value.

Comment: Are you sure the code for the answer to this question is supposed to use `fopen()` and the stream I/O rather than the lower-level POSIX-style file descriptor I/O (`open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()`)?   Using the latter makes the question more nearly sensible.  And back in the days of half-inch magnetic tape drives, buffer sizes really did matter.

Comment: I don't see any mention of the [`dd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) command.  This supports input file and output file, and allows separately specified input and output buffer sizes (and a whole lot more).  This question is asking to emulate parts of that utility.

Answer (score 1):

> I am having problems figuring how to move data between the buffers when the sizes are of different

Layout a plan.  For "some practice problems for job interviews", a good plan and ability to justify it is important.  Coding, although important, is secondary.

```
given valid: 2 FILE *, 2 buffers and their sizes
while  write active && read active
  while write buffer not full && reading active
    if read buffer empty
      read
      update read active
    append min(read buffer length, write buffer available space) of read to write buffer
  if write buffer not empty
    pad write buffer
    write 
    update write active
return file status
```

Now code it.  A more robust solution would use a `struct` to group the `FILE*, buffer, size, offset, length, active` variables.

```
// Return true on problem
static bool rw(FILE *in_s, void *in_buf, size_t in_sz, FILE *out_s,
    void *out_buf, size_t out_sz) {
  size_t in_offset = 0;
  size_t in_length = 0;
  bool in_active = true;
  size_t out_length = 0;
  bool out_active = true;

  while (in_active && out_active) {
    // While room for more data
    while (out_length < out_sz && in_active) {
      if (in_length == 0) {
        in_offset = 0;
        in_length = fread(in_buf, in_sz, 1, in_s);
        in_active = in_length > 0;
      }
      // Append a portion of `in` to `out`
      size_t chunk = min(in_length, out_sz - out_length);
      memcpy((char*) out_buf + out_length, (char*) in_buf + in_offset, chunk);
      out_length += chunk;
      in_length -= chunk;
      in_offset += chunk;
    }

    if (out_length > 0) {
      // Padding only occurs, maybe, on last write
      memset((char*) out_buf + out_length, 0, out_sz - out_length);
      out_active = fwrite(out_buf, out_sz, 1, out_s) == out_sz;
      out_length = 0;
    }
  }
  return ferror(in_s) || ferror(out_s);
}
```

---

Other notes;

1. Casting `malloc()` results not needed. [@Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475326/copy-a-file-with-buffers-of-different-sizes-for-read-and-write/45489257#comment77912920_45475326)

   ```
    // buffer1 = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*bufferSize1);
    buffer1 = malloc (sizeof *buffer1 * bufferSize1);
   ```
2. Use `stderr` for error messages.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475326/copy-a-file-with-buffers-of-different-sizes-for-read-and-write/45489257#comment77914711_45475326)
3. Open the file in binary.
4. `size_t` is more robust for array/buffer sizes than `int`.
5. Consider `sizeof buffer1` vs. `sizeof (buffer1)` as parens not needed with `sizeof object`

Comment: Padding the last `fwrite()` call out to the full write buffer size will result in the copy of the file being larger than the original.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, that was to meet OP's goal of "if file1 is not a multiple of file2, we pad the last buffer transfer with zeros.".  Seems like an odd requirement to me, but that's life with some customer requirements.

Comment: *but that's life with some customer requirements*  LOL

Answer (score 0):

```
while(bytesMoved > 0) {
    for(i=0; i<bytesMoved && i<bufferSize2; i++) 
        buffer2[i]=buffer1[i];

    bytesTransfered+=fwrite(buffer2, i,1,fp2);
    bytesMoved-=i;
}
```

If bufferSize1 is smaller than the filesize you need an outer loop.

Comment: I'm not convinced this deals with the complexity at all.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to your question have indicated, this solution is not the best way to transfer data from 1 file to another file.  However, your case has certain restrictions, which this solution accounts for.

**(1)** Since you are using a buffer, you do not need to read and write `1` char at a time, but instead you can make as few calls to those functions possible.

> size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

:from the man page for `fread`, `nmemb` can = `bufferSize1`

**(2)** You will need to check the return from `fread()` (i.e. `bytesMoved`) and compare it with both of the `bufferSize` 1 and 2.  If **(a)** `bytesMoved` (i.e. return from `fread()`) is equal to `bufferSize1` or if **(b)** `bufferSize2` is less than `bufferSize1` or the return from `fread()`, then you know that there is still data that needs to be read (or written).  So, therefore you should begin the next transfer of data, and when completed return to the previous step you left off on.

**Note:** The pointer to the File Stream in `fread()` and `fwrite()` will begin where it left off in the event that the data is larger than the bufferSizes.

**PseudoCode:**

```
/* in while() loop continue reading from file 1 until nothing is left to read */
while (bytesMoved = fread(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), bufferSize1, fp1))
{

    /* transfer from buffer1 to buffer2 */
    for(i = 0; i < bytesMoved && i < bufferSize2; i++)
        buffer2[i] = buffer1[i];
    buffer2[i] = '\0';

    iterations = 1; /* this is just in case your buffer2 is super tiny and cannot store all from buffer1 */
    /* in while() loop continue writing to file 2 until nothing is left to write 
        to upgrade use strlen(buffer2) instead of bufferSize2 */
    while (bytesTransfered = fwrite(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), bufferSize2, fp2))
    {    
        /* reset buffer2 & write again from buffer1 to buffer2 */
        for(i = bufferSize2 * iterations, j = 0; i < bytesMoved && j < bufferSize2; i++, j++)
            buffer2[j] = buffer1[i];
        buffer2[j] = '\0';
        iterations++;
    }
    /* mem reset buffer1 to prepare for next data transfer*/
}
```

Comment: One nitpick: `fread` and `fwrite` are typically *not* system calls; they are higher-level library functions from `<stdio.h>`.  They are typically implemented on top of lower-level system calls; on Unix-like operating systems those are `read` and `write`.